# find node by tag but not its children with the same tag Xpath python3.4

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xpath

I have xml files like:

```
<root>
    <book>
        <first>
           <book>1</book>
           <book>2</book>
        </first>
     </book>
 </root>
```

using Xpath (predicates = tree.xpath('//book')) I can find all book nodes (3 nodes) such as:

```
<book>
    <first>
       <book>1</book>
       <book>2</book>
    </first>
 </book>
 <book>1</book>
 <book>2</book>
```

but how can I find the book nodes that its parent is not a book node? i.e if found the node book do not look at its children to find more book nodes. 
in my example I should have only:

```
<book>
    <first>
       <book>1</book>
       <book>2</book>
    </first>
 </book>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use

```
tree.xpath('//book[not(ancestor::book)]'))
```

which will not select `book` elements nested into other `book` elements. I assume that by

> find the book nodes that its parent is not a book node

you actually meant finding `book` elements that have no *ancestors* that are `book` elements.

This is the correct XPath expression, I cannnot comment on your code since you did not show it.